# What will happen if master goes down in peer to peer replication?

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, ssms, master-slave-replication

In case of Peer to peer replication, if Master goes down, will the other two nodes continue synchronizing or not?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a Peer-To-Peer replication topology all the nodes are master. So, there is no concept of just ONE master.

The image in your question seems to be made up and wrong. See [original doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017#topologies-that-have-three-or-more-participating-databases).

Read up more on - [Peer-to-Peer - Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017)